# Searching a folder for files matching different strings in an Excel range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, directory

I am using VBA to search a network folder with typically about 4000 .txt files and move the bad ones that contain strings listed in an excel range, to another folder. Remaining good files are zipped and moved/scattered and the .txt's moved to a single folder.

Here is my code that takes many hours to run, probably due to the double looping.  Please help me with changing this to run faster/more efficient.

```
Option Compare Text
Sub SDRFiles()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim Fldr As Object
Dim BaseFldr As String
Dim sdrDNU As String
Dim sdrDateFldr As String
Dim fDate
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FirstTwo As String
Dim NineTen As String
Dim Lead As String
Dim BadFile As Integer
Dim sdrFile As String
Dim fldExists As String

'Process SDR files. Move files off landing zone to working folder, pull out and store bad files,
'zip good files and move to each owner's folder, save good txt in Data Czar's folder.


           'Landing zone
            BaseFldr = "\\nasgw013pn\hedis_prod\SDR FILES"

           'new SDR folder for files
            fDate = Format(Date, "mmddyyyy")

           'Processing fldr
            sdrDateFldr = BaseFldr & "\" & fDate & "_" & shControl.cboMonth.Value & theCycle

            fldExists = Dir(sdrDateFldr)

            If fldExists = "" Then
            MkDir sdrDateFldr
            End If

           'Move all files from landing zone to processing folder
            Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

            extn = "\*.txt"

            FSO.MoveFile Source:=BaseFldr & extn, Destination:=sdrDateFldr & "\"

           'Do Not Use sub folder for bad files
            sdrDNU = sdrDateFldr & "\DNU"

            fldExists = Dir(sdrDNU)
            If fldExists = "" Then
            MkDir sdrDNU
            End If

           'Good Text File destination
            TextFileFldr = fDate & "_" & shControl.cboMonth.Value & theCycle & "_txt"
            TextFileDest = sdrDateFldr & "\" & TextFileFldr

            fldExists = Dir(TextFileDest)
            If fldExists = "" Then
            MkDir TextFileDest
            End If

           'Bottom of bad file strings
            lastRow = shSDR.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            Set xFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sdrDateFldr)

           'loop thru folder
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files     'About 4000 files. can vary
            Fname = xFile.Name
            FirstTwo = Left(Fname, 2)
            NineTen = Mid(Fname, 9, 2)
            Lead = Mid(Fname, 16, 2)

           'range with list of bad strings
        For Each Item In shSDR.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)  'about 10 strings. can vary               

           'Hold file from 1st loop and test.  If bad file, move to Do Not Use (DNU) folder
            If InStr(Fname, Item) > 0 Or _
            (InStr(Fname, "PWOEY") > 0 And FirstTwo <> "OH") Or _
            (InStr(Fname, "HNARST") > 0 And FirstTwo <> NineTen) Or _
            (InStr(Fname, "FTANDHEIPANE") > 0 And FirstTwo <> Lead) Then

           'bad file - move to DNU Folder
            Name sdrDateFldr & "\" & Fname As sdrDNU & "\" & Fname

           'Bad file indentified
            BadFile = 1

       'exit this loop if matched and get next file
        Exit For
            End If
        Next Item

            If BadFile = 0 Then
           'Good file - zip it and move each txt file to same folder
            Call Zipp(sdrDateFldr & "\" & Replace(Fname, "txt", "zip"), sdrDateFldr & "\" & Fname)

           ‘move good zipped file to its own specific folder – NY folder, FL folder TX folder etc.
            Call MoveIt(sdrDateFldr & "\" & Replace(Fname, "txt", "zip"), Replace(Fname, "txt", "zip"))

            End If
            BadFile = 0

    Next xFile

 End Sub

'says function but it really a sub
 Public Function Zipp(ZipName, FileToZip)

 'Called by all modules to create a Zip File
 ‘Dim FSO As Object
 Dim oApp As Object

        If Len(Dir(ZipName)) > 0 Then Kill (ZipName)

        If Dir(ZipName) = "" Then
        Open ZipName For Output As #1
        Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
        Close #1
        End If

        dFile = Dir(FileToZip)

        On Error Resume Next
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        oApp.Namespace(CVar(ZipName)).CopyHere CVar(FileToZip)
        DoEvents            

'====HELP!!! ================Please help me with the following. It hangs sporadically, sometimes at
'============================file 200 or may the 1500th file. I have to esc esc and continue.
'============================For 10 to 20 files it seems to run fine

       'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
        On Error Resume Next
        Do Until oApp.Namespace(CVar(ZipName)).Items.Count = 1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:06"))
        DoEvents
        Loop
    '=============================================================================
'=============================================================================

'USED ONLY BY Sub SDRFiles()
'THIS PART OF ZIPP SAVES THE .TXT FILE TO DATA CZAR'S FOLDER
       'SDR Processing - Move text file
        If SDR = "Y" And Len(Dir(FileToZip)) > 0 Then
        SetAttr FileToZip, vbNormal
        Name FileToZip As TextFileDest & "\" & dFile

        End If            

Set oApp = Nothing
‘Set FSO = Nothing

End Function

Sub MoveIt(PathZip, ZipFileName)

Dim rootPlusSubFolder As String
Dim NasState As Range
Dim NasLocation As String
Dim FSO As Object

'MOVE ZIPP FILES TO FOLDERS
           'MOVE FILES TO IMP FOLDER - find state in extract name and MOVE file to that folder
           'Bottom of state list
            botRow = shNasMoves.Cells(shNasMoves.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

           'Bottom of list of import folder names
            NasBot = Sheets("NASMoves").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Address

           'Look up state to get import folder path
            Application.FindFormat.Clear

            Set NasState = shNasMoves.Range("A1:" & NasBot).Find(What:=Left(ZipFileName, 2))

           'if state found, get folder location URL
            If Not NasState Is Nothing Then
            NasLocation = NasState.Offset(0, 1).Value

           'current month for sub folder file name
            CurMonthFolder = "CS_" & theMo & "_" & theCycle & "\"

           'Combined destination folder and sub folder name
            rootPlusSubFolder = NasLocation & CurMonthFolder

            Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

           'if CS Import SUB folder doesn't exist, create it - sometimes DIR sometimes FSO
            If Not FSO.FolderExists(rootPlusSubFolder) Then
            FSO.CreateFolder (rootPlusSubFolder)
            End If

           'Final dest Fldr
            If Not FSO.FolderExists(rootPlusSubFolder & "\" & "SDR") Then
            FSO.CreateFolder (rootPlusSubFolder & "\" & "SDR")
            End If

  'try to stop pop up
   With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
   End With

          'Debug.Print rootPlusSubFolder & "SDR"

           On Error Resume Next               
          'move file from Root to destination folder/sub folder
           FSO.MoveFile PathZip, rootPlusSubFolder & "SDR\" & ZipFileName

  With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
  End With

           End If
End Sub
```

Comment: SO is for solving a specific error, not improving your code. Suggest you visit Code Review instead.

Comment: If you could post the whole code ('Sub ... - ... End Sub', the procedures Zipp and MoveIt), it would make things much easier. You can replace the sensitive data with bogus data. When rewritten, this should finish in minutes. You can edit your question by clicking on the edit button below your post.

Comment: Start by commenting out all but the folder looping, then check the timing. Add back in the commented sections one by one to see where the slowness is coming from.

Comment: VBasic2008.  I added all the code.  Minutes sounds much better than embarrassing number of hours this takes to run. I welcome advice wherever else I need it

Comment: How do I get this to post in one window?  Help

Comment: @SmileyFtW _SO is for solving a specific error_ that' is only one of the things SO is for.  Moving this Q to Code Review is unnecessary,  and the migration would possibly be rejected.  Q is fine here

Comment: Thanks Chris, any help would be appreciated